# Chrome and Firefox not clearing JSESSIONID cookie causes a redirect loop

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, redirect, cookies, jsessionid

I have an application that receives HTTP/HTTPs requests on Apache Web Server and passes it on to tomcat.

Recently, I've been facing problems with sessions and redirection loops on Google Chrome **and Firefox** browsers after <s>some user logs out</s> the expiration of sessions. I managed to trace down the problem and found that the browser is not clearing the JSESSIONID cookie. After manually clearing that, it starts to work again.

I have checked the log files of Apache Web Server and I found this:

```
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:27 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:29 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:29 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:29 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:30 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:30 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:30 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:31 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:31 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:31 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:32 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:32 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:32 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:33 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:33 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:33 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:34 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:34 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:34 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:35 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
172.16.254.157 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:23:35 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
122.176.45.206 - - [06/Feb/2017:05:24:33 -0600] "GET /preview/login.admin HTTP/1.1" 302 20
```

Apache Server is getting these requests, but nothing is being forwarded to Tomcat.

The network tab of Chrome's *inspect element* window shows me this:
[image]

But this works after I clear the JSESSIONID cookie.

---

This is rather strange, but this issue started about a week ago (The application is working since last 4 years!), and that coincides with the new [update rollout](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/56.0.2924.79..56.0.2924.87?pretty=fuller&n=10000).

I have tried googling stuff and found out that people had similar issues back in 2012 and '15.

<s>Is something really wrong with Chrome?</s> **Are the internet standards changing?** Nonetheless, how can I fix this?

---

### EDIT:

<s>1. The issue is only with Google Chrome.</s>

---

### Edit #2:

1. The problem has started with Mozilla Firefox as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at your traffic it appears to be alternating between http and https.

Two guesses:

(a) there is a redirect rule working against you, e.g. someone thought it would be a good idea to auto-redirect http to https, but not using HSTS.

(b) the site is setting a secure cookie but redirecting to a non-secure endpoint afterward, so the cookie isn't presented; the web site redirects you back to the login page (since you don't look authenticated), which then drops the cookie as part of a session fixation mitigation.

Or (c) the two issues above are interacting to cause the behavior.

Comment: That helped. Thanks :D

Comment: so, how should this be fixed? I have the same issue and got to the same conclusions as in this "answer", but where is the solution?

Comment: how do you solve the (b)? I have the similar issue, but the app is not developed by me and it takes forever to which part of the app causes that.